# Django get_absolute_url() doesn't seem to work in comment section

Tags: django, blogs

I'm trying to get my users to the article page after comments, but something is missing.

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, related_name="comments" ,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    body = RichTextUploadingField(extra_plugins=
    ['youtube', 'codesnippet'], external_plugin_resources= [('youtube','/static/ckeditor/youtube/','plugin.js'), ('codesnippet','/static/ckeditor/codesnippet/','plugin.js')])
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s - %s' % (self.post.title, self.name)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "comentario"
        verbose_name_plural = "comentarios"
        ordering = ['date_added']

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('article-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

urls.py

```
 path('article/<int:pk>/comment/', AddCommentView.as_view(), name='add_comment'),
    path('article/<int:pk>', ArticleDetailView.as_view(), name="article-detail"),
    path('article/edit/<int:pk>', UpdatePostView.as_view(), name='update_post'),
    path('article/<int:pk>/remove', DeletePostView.as_view(), name='delete_post'),
```

For the update_post the get_absolute_url() works. Thanks in advance.

Comment: users after making a comment are getting redirected to "/" but I want them to get redirected to the post view (article-detail)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to pass a parameter which belongs to the ArticleDetailView model. For example if the model for the ArticleDetailView is Post:

```
class ArticleDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Post
```

The get_absolute_url should use a post.pk:

class Comment(models.Model):

```
....
....
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('article-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.post.pk})
```

In your case it is not working as it is using the Comment pk with the Article(Post) view

Comment: It works on my end with simply Comment CreateView - I am being redirected to the Post:

class BlogCommentCreateView(CreateView):
    template_name = 'posts/blog_comment_create.html'
    model = BlogComment
    fields = '__all__'

Can you provide the views.py and the html file for the view?

Answer (score 0):

Ok the thing is I was using this class for comment, had to delete the function of success_url and now works.

```
class AddCommentView(CreateView):
    model = Comment
    form_class = CommentForm
    #form_class = PostForm
    template_name = 'add_comment.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('home')
    def form_valid(self,form):
        form.instance.post_id = self.kwargs['pk']
        return super().form_valid(form)
```